# Class cast exception while create LayerDrawable in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable

i remake my old java code on kotlin now and i have one problem, i need a kotlin analog of this code:

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{
    colorDrawable,
    border
};

LayerDrawable drawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
```

In kotlin i have now:

```
val border = GradientDrawable()
border.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
border.setStroke(CommonsUtils.dpToPx(holder.itemView, 1), Color.parseColor("#DEDEDE"))
border.cornerRadius = CommonsUtils.dpToPx(holder.itemView, 2).toFloat()

val colorDrawable = try {
    Color.parseColor(color.hex)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}

val layers = arrayOf(colorDrawable, border)
val drawable = LayerDrawable(layers as Array<out Drawable>)
```

But arrayOf returns Array of "Any" instead Array of "out Drawable" and i have class cast exception Object[] to Drawable[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

```
val colorDrawable = try {
    ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(color.hex))
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}
```

`Color.parseColor(color.hex)` returns `int` not `Drawable`